# Create a list of named lists from three vectors in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine three vectors into a list of lists, with one vector being the indexes for the list.

Given

```
names<-c("a","b","c","d")
id1<-c(1,1,2,2)
id2<-c(3,4,5,6)
```

I would like to build a list looking like this:

```
mylist <- list("a" = list(1,3), "b" = list(1,4), "c" = list(2,5), "d" = list(2,6))
```

Comment: Highly related but not an *exact* duplicate [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23732591/1478381)

Comment: Yes, that would have helped. I tried searching, but didn't quite know what to search for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `Map`

```
l <- Map(list, id1, id2) # thanks to @thelatemail for suggested improvement
names(l) <- names
identical(mylist, l)
# TRUE
```

Comment: No need for the `i/j` though - `setNames(Map(list,id1,id2),names)` will get you there.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks for this, much better without the new function definition

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `mapply` and the `c` function to concatenate the vectors element-wise. `setNames` conveniently names the result as the function returns:

```
ll <- setNames( mapply( c , id1 , id2 , SIMPLIFY = FALSE ) , names )

#$a
#[1] 1 3

#$b
#[1] 1 4

#$c
#[1] 2 5

#$d
#[1] 2 6
```

or perhaps taking advantage of `mapply()`'s' `USE.NAMES` argument you can name the first vector to do this, achieving the same result without `setNames`:

```
names(id1) <- names
mapply( c , id1 , id2 , SIMPLIFY = FALSE )
```

Comment: This works too. Thank you.
Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to upvote and I set konvas reply as a solution since he was first.

Comment: @MicaelE don't worry! You should always pick the solution that **you** feel best answers **your** question. It's your right. Glad you got some answers and welcome to SO!

Comment: Might be worth noting for future readers that `Map` == `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`.

Comment: @thelatemail well i'll be dammed! I never really used `Map` so I had no idea. So our answers are functionally the same.